# Java type parameter is hiding a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class:

```
public class Widget<COMMAND> {
    // ...
}
```

So I can create instances of it like:

```
Widget<Fizz> fizzWidget = new Widget<Fizz>();
```

Then I have an ABC `BaseWidgetProcessor`, that I want accepting `Widget`s of any type:

```
public abstract class BaseWidgetProcessor<Widget<COMMAND>> {
    public abstract COMMAND process();
}
```

With concrete impls:

```
public abstract class AstroWidgetProcessor<Widget<COMMAND>> {
    @Override
    public COMMAND process() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

etc.

The problem is, with `BaseWidgetProcessor`:

```
public abstract class BaseWidgetProcessor<Widget<COMMAND>> {
    public abstract COMMAND process();
}
```

I get a syntax error:

> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

When I change it to:

```
public abstract class BaseWidgetProcessor<Widget> {
    public abstract COMMAND process();
}
```

The error goes away, but now I get a compiler warning:

> The type parameter Widget is hiding the type Widget

What is going on here?!? Why the error and then respective warning? What's the correct (syntactically) way to set this up?

Comment: lol.  Fizzwidget.  "you damn kids! get off my lawn!  Awww Fizzwidget!"

Comment: Sorry everyone - I made a correction

Comment: Try `public abstract <COMMAND, T extends Widget<COMMAND>> BaseWidget<T>`?

Comment: What's the point of having a constant (generic) parameter? If *WidgetProcessors always have Widget as a parameter, just drop the Widget parameter

Comment: In `class BaseWidgetProcessor<Widget<COMMAND>>`, `Widget` denotes a `type parameter`, not a `class type`.

Comment: Where do you get the syntax error? "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
public abstract class BaseWidgetProcessor<W extends Widget<C>, C> {
    public abstract C process(W widget);
}
```

I added `W widget` as argument to show a bit better the usage.

Now let's say that you have a widget named CoolWidget:

```
public class CoolWidget extends Widget<Integer> {}
```

To declare a CoolWidgetProcessor you would have to do:

```
public class CoolWidgetProcessor extends BaseWidgetProcessor<CoolWidget, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer process(CoolWidget widget) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the most versatile solution, but Bohemian's is preferable if the OP doesn't need to generify the type of processed widgets themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public abstract class BaseWidgetProcessor<COMMAND> {

    protected Widget<COMMAND> widget;

    public BaseWidgetProcessor(Widget<COMMAND> widget) {
        this.widget = widget;
    }

    // presumably uses widget
    public abstract COMMAND process();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian (+1) - that worked. Can you explain why (I'm curious and would like to learn generics better than my current understanding). What's the logical sense of having a WidgetProcessor extend a Widget?!? Thanks again!

Comment: Indeed, what's the logical sense of having FooProcessor extend Foo? Edit: +1 for the composition approach.

Comment: Well it doesn't make much sense, but neither did referring to Widget in the type. Does the second (just added) option work better for you?

Comment: @ignis Does option #2 seem a bit more sane?

Comment: I'm starting to sense that I am modeling my problem wrong. Should I be dropping the generic type on Widget altogether? So instead of `Widget<Command>`, just make `Widget` a non-generic interface? If not, what is the right way to model my problem?

Comment: +1 But I would just remove the first example to echo @ignis's comment.

Comment: @PaulBellora Done. (removed it). Just because it compiled didn't make it a "good answer". Actually probably did more harm than good, if you see OP's later comment.

Comment: @TicketMonster I can't answer your comment, because you haven't told us what you're trying to do/solve. I can probably say that if Widget does things to/with a type, then it should be generic.  You jumped straight into code and compiler errors without context: Maybe add some more preamble to your question.