# Double-nested Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344445/java-type-parameter-is-hiding-a-generic-type) this morning, thought I had it answered, actually implemented the proposed solution, and it failed to do what I need. So here's my full problem:

I have the following classes:

```
// Objects to process.
public class Apple {
    private Color color;
    private int numberOfSeeds;
    // ...
}

public class Chair {
    private Material madeOutOfMaterial;
    private double price;
    // ...
}

public class CellPhone {
    private Manufacturer make;
    private String model;
    private boolean isSmartPhone;
    // ...
}

// Contains the object that will be processed (an Apple, Chair, CellPhone instance, etc.)
// as well as metadata info about the processing itself (timestamp, a UUID for tracking
// purposes, etc.).
public class ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> {
    private PROCESSABLE_OBJECT result;
    private Date processedOnDate;
    private String uuid;
    // ...
}

// Abstract base class for processing PROCESSABLE_OBJECTs.
public abstract class ObjectProcessor<ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>> {
    private String name;

    public abstract ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> process(Data data);
}

// One concrete processor.
public class SimpleObjectProcessor extends ObjectProcessor<ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>> {
    private Fizz fizz;

    @Override
    public ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> process(Data data) {
        // Processes data one way, and returns a PROCESSABLE_OBJECT.
    }
}

// Another concrete processor.
public class ComplexObjectProcessor extends ObjectProcessor<ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>> {
    private Buzz buzz;

    @Override
    public ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> process(Data data) {
        // Processes data differently, and returns a PROCESSABLE_OBJECT.
    }
}
```

So that the final code, using all of these classes looks like this:

```
ObjectProcessor<ProcessingMetadata<Apple>> appleProcessor =
        new ComplexObjectProcessor<ProcessingMetadata<Apple>>();
Data data = getData();

ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> meta = appleProcessor.process(data);

Apple apple = meta.getResult();
Date processedOn = meta.getProcessedOnDate();
String uuid = meta.getUUID();
```

This is the "API" that I want exposed to the developer. Grab some `Data`, select a typed processor, process the data, and get all the metadata you need.

The problem is that my `ObjectProcessor<ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>>` isn't legal. It gives me the following compiler error on the `ProcessingMetadata` portion of the class definition:

> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

I have played with this class (and its concrete subclasses) all morning, and can't seem to get generics set up correctly to give me the API that I want. I'm open to requiring the `PROCESSABLE_OBJECT`s to actually being an interface, such as `Processable`, and having `Apple`, `Chair`, etc. implement it. But there's no telling what the client is going to want to process, and so I'd prefer not to force them to make their POJOs implement a `Processabl` interface, if at all possible.

So, **is my desired API possible?** If so, how? If not, then why, and what is the closest I can get to it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding a space to the ending `>>`: `> >`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the items in the type parameter list needs to be a type parameter. In the class declaration of ObjectProcessor, `ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>` is not a generic type parameter.

You could specify PROCESSABLE_OBJECT as a parameterized type, and then specify a type extending ProcessingMetaData as another parameterized type.

```
public abstract class ObjectProcessor< 
   PROCESSING_METADATA extends ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>, 
   PROCESSABLE_OBJECT > 
{ ... }
```

**EDIT:**

Your subclasses are also parameterized types. You need to declare those type parameters on the class itself. Then you can use them to parameterize the superclass.

```
public class SimpleObjectProcessor<
   PROCESSING_METADATA extends ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>, 
   PROCESSABLE_OBJECT > 
extends ObjectProcessor< PROCESSING_METADATA,PROCESSABLE_OBJECT > 
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy Thomas (+1) - can you show me what one of the concrete processors' definition might look like (`SimpleObjectProcessor` or `ComplexObjectProcessor`, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your api, the developer would use this line

```
ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> meta = appleProcessor.process(data);
```

as this

```
ProcessingMetadata<Apple> meta = appleProcessor.process(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The class declaration itself only takes a type parameter declaration, but you try to put `ProcessingMetadata` there.

```
public abstract class ObjectProcessor<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> {
    private String name;

    public abstract ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> process(Data data);
}

public class SimpleObjectProcessor<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT>
        extends ObjectProcessor<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> {
    private Fizz fizz;

    @Override
    public ProcessingMetadata<PROCESSABLE_OBJECT> process(Data data) {
        // Processes data one way, and returns a PROCESSABLE_OBJECT.
    }
}

ObjectProcessor<Apple> appleProcessor = new ComplexObjectProcessor<Apple>();
// Note: there is no PROCESSABLE_OBJECT here. Use the concrete type:
ProcessingMetadata<Apple> meta = appleProcessor.process(data);
```